EF Core 9 : the database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)
I am using DDD architecture and the following code changes the aggregate root (basically adds a comment which is an entity to the aggregate root).
public sealed class AddCommentToPostCommandHandlers : ICommandHandler<AddCommentToPostCommand, Guid>
{
    private readonly IPostCommandRepository _postRepository;
    private readonly ILogger<AddCommentToPostCommandHandlers> _logger;

    public AddCommentToPostCommandHandlers(IPostCommandRepository postRepository, ILogger<AddCommentToPostCommandHandlers> logger)
    {
        _postRepository = postRepository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Result<Guid>> Handle(AddCommentToPostCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var post = await _postRepository.GetGraphByAsync(request.PostId, cancellationToken);

        if (post is not null)
        {
            post.AddComment(request.DisplayName, request.Email, request.CommentText);

            if (post.Result.IsSuccess)
            {
                _postRepository.UpdateBy(post);

                await _postRepository.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);

                return post.Id;
            }

            return post.Result;
        }

        return Result.Fail(ErrorMessages.NotFound(request.ToString()));
    }
}

This code worked fine with EF Core 8, but when I upgraded to EF Core 9, I get the following error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The
database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since
entities were loaded.

This error also occurs when editing a comment, whereas in the previous version (EF Core 8) this error did not occur.
Aggregate root code:
namespace ContentService.Core.Domain.Aggregates.Posts;

public class Post : AggregateRoot<Post>
{
    public Title Title { get; private set; }
    public Description Description { get; private set; }

    public Text Text { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<GuidId> _categoryIds;

    public virtual IReadOnlyList<GuidId> CategoryIds => _categoryIds;

    #region بارگذاری تنبل در سطح دامنه

    private List<Comment> _comments;

    public virtual IReadOnlyList<Comment> Comments
    {
        get
        {
            if (_comments == null)
            {
                LoadComments();
            }

            return _comments.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    private void LoadComments()
    {
        // Load comments from the data source here.
        // This is just a placeholder. You will need to replace this with your actual data loading logic.

        _comments = new List<Comment>();
    }

    #endregion End بارگذاری تنبل در سطح دامنه

    public Post()
    {
        _categoryIds = new List<GuidId>();
    }

    private Post(string? title, string? description, string? text) : this()
    {
        var titleResult = Title.Create(title);

        Result.WithErrors(titleResult.Errors);

        var descriptionResult = Description.Create(description);

        Result.WithErrors(descriptionResult.Errors);

        var contentResult = Text.Create(text);

        Result.WithErrors(contentResult.Errors);

        if (Result.IsSuccess)
        {
            Title = titleResult.Value;
            Description = descriptionResult.Value;
            Text = contentResult.Value;
        }
    }

    public Post Create(string? title, string? description, string? text)
    {
        var checkValidations = new Post(title, description, text);

        Result.WithErrors(checkValidations.Result.Errors);

        if (Result.IsFailed) 
            return this;

        if (Result.IsSuccess)
        {
            this.Text = checkValidations.Text;
            this.Title = checkValidations.Title;
            this.Description = checkValidations.Description;

            RaiseDomainEvent(new PostCreatedEvent(Id, this.Title.Value, this.Description.Value, this.Text.Value));
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Post UpdatePost(string? title, string? description, string? text)
    {
        var checkValidations = new Post(title, description, text);

        Result.WithErrors(checkValidations.Result.Errors);

        if (Result.IsFailed) 
            return this;

        if (Result.IsSuccess)
        {
            this.Title = checkValidations.Title;
            this.Description = checkValidations.Description;
            this.Text = checkValidations.Text;

            RaiseDomainEvent(new PostUpdatedEvent(Id, Title.Value!, Description.Value!, Text.Value!));

            Result.WithSuccess(SuccessMessages.SuccessUpdate(DataDictionary.Post));
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Post RemovePost(Guid? id)
    {
        var guidResult = GuidId.Create(id);

        if (guidResult.IsFailed)
        {
            Result.WithErrors(guidResult.Errors);
            return this;
        }

        // Note: if have IsDeleted property (soft delete) we can change to true here
        RaiseDomainEvent(new PostRemovedEvent(id));

        Result.WithSuccess(SuccessMessages.SuccessDelete(DataDictionary.Post));

        return this;
    }

    #region Category

    public Post AddCategory(Guid? categoryId)
    {
        var guidResult = GuidId.Create(categoryId);

        if (guidResult.IsFailed)
        {
            Result.WithErrors(guidResult.Errors);
            return this;
        }

        if (!_categoryIds.Contains(guidResult.Value))       //جلوگیری از تکراری بودن دسته بندی  
        {
            _categoryIds.Add(guidResult.Value);

            RaiseDomainEvent(new PostCategoryAddedEvent(Id, (Guid)categoryId!));
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Post ChangeCategory(Guid? oldCategoryId, Guid? newCategoryId)
    {
        var oldGuidResult = GuidId.Create(oldCategoryId);
        var newGuidResult = GuidId.Create(newCategoryId);

        if (oldGuidResult.IsFailed)
        {
            Result.WithErrors(oldGuidResult.Errors);
            return this;
        }

        if (newGuidResult.IsFailed)
        {
            Result.WithErrors(newGuidResult.Errors);
            return this;
        }

        if (_categoryIds.Contains(oldGuidResult.Value))
        {
            var indexOldCategory = _categoryIds.IndexOf(oldGuidResult.Value);

            if (!_categoryIds.Contains(newGuidResult.Value))
            {
                _categoryIds.RemoveAt(indexOldCategory);
                _categoryIds.Insert(indexOldCategory, newGuidResult.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                _categoryIds.RemoveAt(indexOldCategory);
            }

            RaiseDomainEvent(new CategoryPostChangedEvent(Id, (Guid)oldCategoryId!, (Guid)newCategoryId!));
        }
        else
        {
            Result.WithError(ErrorMessages.NotFound(DataDictionary.Category));
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Post RemoveCategory(Guid? categoryId)
    {
        var guidResult = GuidId.Create(categoryId);

        if (guidResult.IsFailed)
        {
            Result.WithErrors(guidResult.Errors);
            return this;
        }

        if (_categoryIds.Contains(guidResult.Value))
        {
            _categoryIds.Remove(guidResult.Value);

            RaiseDomainEvent(new CategoryPostRemovedEvent(Id, (Guid)categoryId!));
        }

        return this;
    }

    #endregion End Category

    #region Comments

    public Post AddComment(string? name, string? email, string? text)

    {

        var commentResult = Comment.Create(this, name, email, text);

        Result.WithErrors(commentResult.Errors);

        if (Result.IsFailed)

        {

            return this;

        }

        var hasAny = Comments

            .Any(c => c.Name == commentResult.Value.Name

                      && c.Email == commentResult.Value.Email

                      && c.CommentText == commentResult.Value.CommentText);

        if (hasAny)

        {

            var errorMessage = ValidationMessages.Repetitive(DataDictionary.Comment);

            Result.WithError(errorMessage);

            return this;

        }

        _comments.Add(commentResult.Value);

        RaiseDomainEvent(new CommentAddedEvent(this.Id, commentResult.Value.Id, commentResult.Value.Name.Value, commentResult.Value.Email.Value, commentResult.Value.CommentText.Value));

        return this;

    }

    public Post ChangeCommentText(string? name, string? email, string? text, string? newText)

    {

        var commentOldResult = Comment.Create(this, name, email, text);

        var commentNewResult = Comment.Create(this, name, email, newText);

        Result.WithErrors(commentOldResult.Errors);

        Result.WithErrors(commentNewResult.Errors);

        var emailGuardResult = Guard.CheckIf(commentNewResult.Value.Email, DataDictionary.Email)

            .Equal(commentOldResult.Value.Email);

        Result.WithErrors(emailGuardResult.Errors);

        var nameGuardResult = Guard.CheckIf(commentNewResult.Value.Name, DataDictionary.Name)

            .Equal(commentOldResult.Value.Name);

        Result.WithErrors(nameGuardResult.Errors);

        var commentTextGuardResult = Guard.CheckIf(commentNewResult.Value.CommentText, DataDictionary.CommentText)

            .NotEqual(commentOldResult.Value.CommentText);

        Result.WithErrors(commentTextGuardResult.Errors);

        if (Result.IsFailed)

        {

            return this;

        }

        LoadComments();

        var hasAny = Comments

            .Any(c => c.Name == commentNewResult.Value.Name

                      && c.Email == commentNewResult.Value.Email

                      && c.CommentText == commentNewResult.Value.CommentText);

        if (hasAny)

        {

            var errorMessage = ValidationMessages.Repetitive(DataDictionary.Comment);

            Result.WithError(errorMessage);

            return this;

        }

        //var commentIndex = _comments

        //  .FindIndex(c => c.Name == commentOldResult.Value.Name

        //            && c.Email == commentOldResult.Value.Email

        //            && c.CommentText == commentOldResult.Value.CommentText);

        var commentIndex = Comments

            .Select((c, i) => new { Comment = c, Index = i })

            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Comment.Name == commentOldResult.Value.Name

                                 && x.Comment.Email == commentOldResult.Value.Email

                                 && x.Comment.CommentText == commentOldResult.Value.CommentText)?.Index;

        if (commentIndex >= 0)

        {

            _comments.RemoveAt((int)commentIndex);

            _comments.Insert((int)commentIndex, commentNewResult.Value);

            RaiseDomainEvent(new CommentEditedEvent(this.Id, commentNewResult.Value.Id, commentNewResult.Value.Name.Value, commentNewResult.Value.Email.Value, commentNewResult.Value.CommentText.Value));

        }

        return this;

    }

    public Post RemoveComment(string? name, string? email, string? text)

    {

        var commentResult = Comment.Create(this, name, email, text);

        Result.WithErrors(commentResult.Errors);

        if (Result.IsFailed)

        {

            return this;

        }

        var commentFounded = Comments

            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name?.Value?.ToLower() == commentResult.Value.Name?.Value?.ToLower()

                                 && c.Email?.Value?.ToLower() == commentResult.Value?.Email?.Value?.ToLower()

                                 && c.CommentText.Value?.ToLower() == commentResult?.Value?.CommentText.Value?.ToLower());

        if (commentFounded is null)

        {

            var errorMessage = ErrorMessages.NotFound(DataDictionary.Comment);

            Result.WithError(errorMessage);

            return this;

        }

        _comments.Remove(commentFounded);

        Result.WithSuccess(SuccessMessages.SuccessDelete(DataDictionary.Comment));

        RaiseDomainEvent(new CommentRemovedEvent(Id, name, email, text));

        return this;

    }

    #endregion

}

and comment entity is:

namespace ContentService.Core.Domain.Aggregates.Posts.Entities;

public class Comment : Entity

{

    public DisplayName Name { get; private set; }

    public Email Email { get; private set; }

    public CommentText CommentText { get; private set; }

    public Guid PostId { get; private set; }

    private Comment()

    {

    }

    private Comment(Guid postId, DisplayName name, Email email, CommentText text) : this()

    {

        PostId = postId;

        Name = name;

        Email = email;

        CommentText = text;

    }

    public static Result<Comment> Create(Guid? postId, string? name, string? email, string? text)

    {

        Result<Comment> result = new();

        if (!postId.HasValue || postId == Guid.Empty)

        {

            var errorMessage = ValidationMessages.Required(DataDictionary.Post);

            result.WithError(errorMessage);

        }

        var displayNameResult = DisplayName.Create(name);

        result.WithErrors(displayNameResult.Errors);

        var emailResult = Email.Create(email);

        result.WithErrors(emailResult.Errors);

        var textResult = CommentText.Create(text);

        result.WithErrors(textResult.Errors);

        if (result.IsFailed)

        {

            return result;

        }

        var returnValue = new Comment((Guid)postId!, displayNameResult.Value, emailResult.Value, textResult.Value);

        result.WithValue(returnValue);

        return result;

    }

}

and ef config:
internal sealed class PostConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>

{

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)

    {

        builder.Property(p => p.CategoryIds)

            .HasConversion(

                v => string.Join(',', v.Select(c => c.Value)),

                v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(c => GuidId.Create(c).Value).ToList()

            );

        builder.Property(p => p.Title)

            .IsRequired(true)

            .HasMaxLength(Title.Maximum)

            .HasConversion(p => p.Value, p => Title.Create(p).Value);

        builder.Property(p => p.Description)

            .IsRequired(true)

            .HasMaxLength(Description.Maximum)

            .HasConversion(d => d.Value, d => Description.Create(d).Value);

        builder.Property(p => p.Text)

            .IsRequired(true)

            .HasConversion(t => t.Value, t => Text.Create(t).Value);

        builder.OwnsMany<Comment>(c => c.Comments, cc =>

        {

            cc.ToTable("Comments");

            cc.Property(c => c.Email)

                .IsRequired(true)

                .HasConversion(e => e.Value, e => Email.Create(e).Value);

            cc.Property(c => c.Name)

                .IsRequired(true)

                .HasMaxLength(DisplayName.Maximum)

                .HasConversion(e => e.Value, e => DisplayName.Create(e).Value);

            cc.Property(c => c.CommentText)

                .IsRequired(true)

                .HasMaxLength(CommentText.Maximum)

                .HasConversion(e => e.Value, e => CommentText.Create(e).Value);

        });

    }

}


This question is similar to: Unable to edit db entries using EFCore, EntityState.Modified: "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please turn this into a [mre] with an emphasis on 'minimal'.

I found the problem. Since I have defined a single entity in the database Post and Comment. And on the other hand, the DDD rules say that it should be a reference to the id and not the object itself. In case I mistakenly considered Post and Comment as two different entities. For this reason, the entity code (entity in DDD) Comment was a reference to the id:
using ContentService.Core.Domain.Aggregates.Posts.ValueObjects;

using FluentResults;

using MDF.Framework.SeedWork;
using MDF.Resources.Common;
using MDF.Resources.Common.FormattedMessages;

namespace ContentService.Core.Domain.Aggregates.Posts.Entities;
public class Comment : Entity
{
    public DisplayName Name { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
    public CommentText CommentText { get; private set; }
    public Guid PostId { get; private set; }
    private Comment()
    {

    }
    private Comment(Guid postId, DisplayName name, Email email, CommentText text) : this()
    {
        PostId = postId;
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        CommentText = text;
    }

    public static Result<Comment> Create(Guid? postId, string? name, string? email, string? text)
    {
        Result<Comment> result = new();

        if (!postId.HasValue || postId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            var errorMessage = ValidationMessages.Required(DataDictionary.Post);
            result.WithError(errorMessage);
        }

        var displayNameResult = DisplayName.Create(name);
        result.WithErrors(displayNameResult.Errors);

        var emailResult = Email.Create(email);
        result.WithErrors(emailResult.Errors);

        var textResult = CommentText.Create(text);
        result.WithErrors(textResult.Errors);

        if (result.IsFailed)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var returnValue = new Comment((Guid)postId!, displayNameResult.Value, emailResult.Value, textResult.Value);
        result.WithValue(returnValue);
        return result;
    }

}

Notice the Guid postId in the code above. But I should have referenced the object like this:
using ContentService.Core.Domain.Aggregates.Posts.ValueObjects;

using FluentResults;

using MDF.Framework.SeedWork;
using MDF.Resources.Common;
using MDF.Resources.Common.FormattedMessages;

namespace ContentService.Core.Domain.Aggregates.Posts.Entities;
public class Comment : Entity
{
    public DisplayName Name { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
    public CommentText CommentText { get; private set; }
    public Post Post { get; private set; }
    private Comment()
    {

    }
    private Comment(Post post, DisplayName name, Email email, CommentText text) : this()
    {
        Post = post;
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        CommentText = text;
    }

    public static Result<Comment> Create(Post? post, string? name, string? email, string? text)
    {
        Result<Comment> result = new();

        if (post is null)
        {
            var errorMessage = ValidationMessages.Required(DataDictionary.Post);
            result.WithError(errorMessage);
        }

        var displayNameResult = DisplayName.Create(name);
        result.WithErrors(displayNameResult.Errors);

        var emailResult = Email.Create(email);
        result.WithErrors(emailResult.Errors);

        var textResult = CommentText.Create(text);
        result.WithErrors(textResult.Errors);

        if (result.IsFailed)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var returnValue = new Comment(post!, displayNameResult.Value, emailResult.Value, textResult.Value);
        result.WithValue(returnValue);
        return result;
    }

}

In the above code which works correctly, instead of referencing the id in the Comment class, there is a reference to the Post object. Because Post and Comment are one entity and not different entities.

The problem is the phrase I am using DDD architecture. It looks like you're trying to follow some recipe instead of actually using DDD. DDD has nothing to do with ORMs like EF Core. Or with the code you posted here - DDD is a high-level concept (not architecture) and doesn't say all entities should have a custom factory method instead of a constructor. Much less that they should hard-code validation inside the entities instead of using an outside service. Result types aren't meant for validation either and .NET itself already has its own validation abstractions.

So much code to do something that could have been done magnitudes simpler with basic entity classes, even accounting for the more DDD approach...
That said, I think the issue will be with how Comments is declared as a ReadOnlyCollection and the logic you have embedded there. EF Core 9 has added capabilities to recognize and use Read-only collections and this is probably not compatible with your approach:
private List<Comment> _comments;

public virtual IReadOnlyList<Comment> Comments
{
    get
    {
        if (_comments == null)
        {
            LoadComments();
        }

        return _comments.AsReadOnly();
    }
}

Regardless, this isn't a good design as you are essentially trying to replicate lazy loading. With a backing field to satisfy DDD, simplify this to:
private readonly List<Comment> _comments = [];
public virtual IReadOnlyList<Comment> Comments => _comments;

Never expose a setter for a collection navigation property. When you want to work with a Post and access its collection of comments you have two choices, either ensure your code eager loads the collection when the Post is retrieved, or enable lazy loading. The first option is preferable. EF Core 9 should now recognize the ReadOnlyCollection and cooperate with backing fields. I'm not sure how that code might have worked in EF Core 8 without explicit configuration to tell EF to use the backing field "_comments".
Wrapping the entities in a Repository will only serve to restrain what you can leverage from EF so I highly recommend AVOIDING the idea of a PostRepository or worse, a PostRepository and CommentRepository. If you want to create an abstraction to make things easier to test, then create a Repository to serve the class consuming posts (and comments) and expose _context.Posts via IQueryable<Post>: I.e.
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
{
    IQueryable<Post> query = _context.Posts;
    // append any common filters like IsActive or authorization checks etc.
    return query;
}

public IQueryable<Post> GetPostById(int postId)
{
    IQueryable<Post> query = _context.Posts
        .Where(x => x.PostId == postId);
    // append any common filters like IsActive or authorization checks etc.
    return query;
}    

A repository like this is easier to mock than a DbSet. Why IQueryable, even for GetById? Because it gives your consumer the flexibility and access to the capabilities of EF. If you want a Post and include its Comments:
    var post = Repository.GetPostById(postId)
        .Include(x => x.Comments)
        .Single();

The consumer also has the ability to project (Select) or simply do an exists check with .Any(), plus perform operations synchronously or asynchronously. Lightweight, flexible, and easier to mock out. If you don't have base rules or need unit testing then just use the Repository pattern EF already provides in the form of the DbSet<T>.

No need to change the PostConfiguration.cs class?

Other than going completely overboard with custom types. Also a comma-delimited list of CategoryIds will not work for managing FKs to categories. If the relationship is one-to-many then Category needs a PostId, or more likely if many-to-many then there needs to be a PostCategory table with the PostId & CategoryId. You are doing a lot of unnecessary work. Keep it magnitudes simpler. Custom types for instance are usually reserved for FK/PK columns to help add meaning. The more complexity you add, the more places bugs and issues have to embed themselves.

If you are stuck with an existing schema that has a comma-delimited list of categoryIds then Post-Category relationships won't be managed by EF and won't be usable in Linq Queries. You would need to have a cached copy of categories available in memory to resolve after fetching the Post(s). With a de-normalized relationship like that, finding Posts by Category gets very difficult to do efficiently. To have any sort of search-ability in a delimited list, it should be bounded. Instead of "1,2,3,10", "~1~~2~~3~~10~". Easier to differentiate "1" from "10" regardless of position in list.
